# Assign a variable to the output of a stored procedure

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, variable-assignment

I am trying to assign the output of a stored procedure to a variable using T-SQL

I have a stored procedure that I pass a varbinary(128) variable and it decrypts it using a key  and has an output variable for the decrypted value. I'm not sure if my syntax is correct because when I run the procedure it gives the correct result but when I assign to a variable, then select the variable it is always null

```
declare @e as varbinary(128)
set @e = *encrypted value*
declare @t as int
set @t = 0
exec *storedprocedure* @data = @e,@t output
select @t
```

t is null when I select above

Comment: what about the stored procedure code? You are not setting the OUTPUT parameter... are you trying to using RETURN?

Comment: How are you calling the proc from the backend? Are you passing in the out parameter to the SqlCommmand and flagging it as such? Once you call ExecuteNonQuery you need to read the value from the outparamter as follows: string result = outparam.Value.ToString(); //just an example

Comment: Please show the Stored Procedure's code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example

```
CREATE PROC myProc @in INT, @out INT OUTPUT
AS 
    SELECT @out = @in+20

GO

DECLARE @in INT, @out INT 

SET @in = 1

EXEC myProc @in= @in, @out=@out OUTPUT

SELECT @out

DROP PROC myProc
```